# SQL Query involving Join

Tags: sql, join

I have a table called mixpanel with the folliowing columns

```
merchant_name
date
event_type (2 types 'Loaded a page', 'Clicked')
```

I also have a table called google_webmaster table with the following columns

```
merchant_name
gw_clicks
gw_impressions
device (Can be PC, Mobile or Tablet)
date
```

What I am trying to do is join these 2 tables based on merchant_name and trying to get merchant name, sum(Loaded a Page), sum (clicks), gw_impressions, gw_clicks

Here is my current query

```
SELECT 
a.merchant_name,
b.gw_impressions, 
b.gw_clicks, 
SUM(CASE WHEN event_type = 'Loaded a Page' then 1 else 0 end) mxp_impressions, 
SUM(CASE WHEN event_type = 'Clicked' then 1     else 0 end) mxp_clicks
from mixpanel a
inner join google_webmaster b on a.merchant_name = b.merchant_name 
where a.time >= '2015-07-15 00:00:00' AND a.time <= '2015-07-15 23:59:59' and b.date = '2015-07-15' 
group by 1,2,3
```

The problem with this query is that it is joining 3 rows of each merchant record from webmaster table to mixpanel table. This is because there are 3 rows for each PC, Mobile, Tablet in the webmaster table.

How can I just get 1 record in the join (for each merchant) that sums gw_impressions. gw_clicks for PC, Mobile and Tablet.

Comment: some data input and desire result would help. And you could provide some [**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90e4d/5)

Comment: Maybe create and link to a simple example with example data using http://sqlfiddle.com/ so others can see better what you mean

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
a.merchant_name,
b.device,
SUM(b.gw_impressions + b.gw_clicks),
SUM(CASE WHEN event_type = 'Loaded a Page' then 1 else 0 end) mxp_impressions, 
SUM(CASE WHEN event_type = 'Clicked' then 1 else 0 end) mxp_clicks
from mixpanel a
inner join google_webmaster b on a.merchant_name = b.merchant_name 
where a.time >= '2015-07-15 00:00:00' 
AND a.time <= '2015-07-15 23:59:59' 
and b.date = '2015-07-15' 
group by 1,2
```

Added `device` in the query and summed up gw_impressions, gw_clicks.